# Return T where are different return types

Tags: c#, syndication, syndication-feed, syndication-item

I have different return types so I can't decide what to use for that.
I was thinking something like that below, but if you have other ideas I am open for that.

```cs
public T GetValue<T>(ContentType type)
{
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ContentType.BaseUri:
                return item.BaseUri;
                break;
            case ContentType.Categories:
                return item.Categories;
                break;
            case ContentType.Content:
                return item.Content;
                break;
            case ContentType.Contributors:
                return item.Contributors;
                break;
            case ContentType.Copyright:
                return item.Copyright;
                break;
          }
     }
}

public enum ContentType
{
    BaseUri,
    Categories,
    Content,
    Contributors,
    Copyright
}
```

I would like to decide what type I want to return so It matches, otherwise it would drop an compile time error.

Comment: if you find your self switching like this or using typeof in a generic method, its *usually* a sign of something is wrong and you need to think about this again. to answer your question, you cant do this type of thing at run-time. this would come under the banner of magical inference.. however you can return an object

Comment: It's not clear where you'd expect the compile-time error to occur. What if I were to call this from another generic method accepting a `ContentType` - that won't know at compile-time what the content type is. Even if you're calling it from a non-generic method, you may have a variable content type... and arguably if you don't, you should be accessing the property directly instead anyway. If you could give more context about how you expect this to interact with calling code, it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: your problem is vague. try returning object, look "as" and "is" keywords

Comment: Don´t treat completely different types alltogether in a single member **pretending** they have something in common. If they do not you shouldn´t use generics but have five different methods. If they do, extract common base-type and make the method have a generic sonstraint.

Comment: I saw a solution for this one. Maybe I just misunderstood that, but I wrote that in the answer.

Comment: @mehrandvd OP is asking about things you are master at.

Comment: Since the `T` has to be specified *on the calling end of this call*, it should be clear that the method cannot *change* this `T` as part of the call. You will have to settle on a `T` that all the objects inherit from, which ultimately could be `object`. It might make more sense to make the `T` control which item you want. Nevertheless, the code is going to be very odd, full of casts. You sure this is the right approach? Why can't the calling code do this: `var copyright = feed.Items.First().Copyright;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the point of putting the switch case in a for loop. you will exit the loop the first time one of the cases of your switch is true.
But to handle the problem on uncertainty about the return type, in case you know that the return type would be a reference type, then you can do this too:

You can set the return type to `object` and then the caller has to do a casting:

```
public object GetValue(ContentType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case ContentType.BaseUri:
            return item.BaseUri;
            break;
        case ContentType.Categories:
            return item.Categories;
            break;
        case ContentType.Content:
            return item.Content;
            break;
        case ContentType.Contributors:
            return item.Contributors;
            break;
        case ContentType.Copyright:
            return item.Copyright;
            break;
      }
}
```

caller:

```
public void Caller() 
{
    object x = GetValue();
    if ( x.GetType() == typeof(BaseUri) ) // I assume that BaseUri is also a class name
    {
        BaseUri baseUri = (BaseUri)x;
        // now you can use baseUri to initialize another variable in outer scopes ... or use it as a parameter to some method or ...
    }
    else if(x.GetType() == typeof(Category))
    {
        // the same logic of casting and using goes here too ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw this yesterday and I was curious how can I reproduce it.

```
        // Summary:
        //     Returns value of specified property as Sandbox.ModAPI.Interfaces.ITerminalProperty.TypeName
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   block:
        //     block reference
        //
        //   propertyId:
        //     property id (name)
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   T:
        //     required value type of Sandbox.ModAPI.Interfaces.ITerminalProperty.TypeName
        //
        // Returns:
        //     property value as Sandbox.ModAPI.Interfaces.ITerminalProperty.TypeName
        public static T GetValue<T>(this Ingame.IMyTerminalBlock block, string propertyId);
```

This is how you call it. `item.GetValue<StringBuilder>("gpsCoords")`
And you can ask another property with different type. `item.GetValue<bool>("IsPerm")`

*The code owner: https://github.com/malware-dev/MDK-SE*

Comment: This is not an answer to your posted question.  Your question should be updated to include this information.  If this is not related to your question above, it should be posted as a new question.  Either way, this answer should be deleted.